# My Chrome browser waits until a local URL request to the same URL is finished before it starts a new one

Tags: express, google-chrome, localhost

Summary: Just `ctrl`+`f5` solves it, but it's very annoying.

---

For WEB development, I often connect to the web server running on localhost using the Chrome browser.

However, if you access the exact same url in two chrome windows at the same time, the other one does not even start until the execution of either one is completed.

More precisely, I had already opened the url of the same address in two chrome windows, and quickly pressed the `f5` key in the two windows.

I deliberately made my local webserver wait 5 seconds before responding very slowly for testing purposes.

And it left logs before and after waiting 5 seconds.

If the above phenomenon occurs, the log of the start of the second request is not output until the log of the end of waiting for 5 seconds of the first request is output.

If I use `ctrl`+`f5` instead of `f5` to bypass the cache and refresh, this doesn't happen.

Of course, there is no problem when the address is different. For example:

```
http://localhost:3000/path?a=1
http://localhost:3000/path?a=2
```

Also, when I use the chrome incognito window feature, requesting one in a normal window and the other in an incognito window, the problem does not occur. (But again when two incognito...)

And the cache header didn't help me. Full code for reference:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    res.set('Cache-control', 'no-store');
    // res.set('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
    // res.set('Cache-control', 'max-age=0');
    // res.set('Cache-control', 'public, max-age=0');
    // res.set('Cache-control', 'private, max-age=0');

    const id = Math.random();
    console.log(id, 'wait start.');
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 5000));
    console.log(id, 'wait end.');
    res.send(String(id));

});

app.listen(3000);
```

This isn't a big problem. But I'm wasting a lot of time just forgetting the `ctrl` key.

Any ideas that might help me?